# Deleted Wordpress page appears in Google Search Results

Tags: pages

I created a page (https://padigital.org/rights/) to test something, then deleted it. It still appears in Google searches. However, it no longer appears in the Admin Dashboard, so I'm unable to delete/make it private. How do I find it to delete it again?

Answer (score 1):

Since that page has already been indexed you can do a couple things.

**1** - Add a rule in your .htaccess file that tells search engines not to index the page

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /rights
```

**2** - Use Google's Remove URLs Tool.  The Remove URLs tool enables you to temporarily block pages from Google Search results.  You can [start that process here](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal).

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry, google check your page with the time and remove automatically.

Also, you can enter in your search console of google and resend your sitemaps